# Wix installer with .NET Application handle component downgrades

Tags: .net, nuget, wix, windows-installer

I am not very experienced with wix. But i run into following problem.

Generally i do not allow downgrade with the installer. But i have thousands of third party library dependencies.

So when i create a new installer and wanna update a running system i get sometimes into following problem.

Current installation:
A third party library A depends on another third party library B with Version 5.0.0.
A -> B (5.0.0)

So during updating of some nuget package, the implicit reference to the third party library A is removed.
But i get another library C which depends also on library B, but only with Version 3.0.0

When building the installer and try to install the new application, following occures:
Installed Version of B is 5.0.0.
New Version of B is 3.0.0.
The installer does not allow downgrades and remove the entire library B.
B is missing when application is installed.

How can I handle this problem?

For the moment, i don't allow an update of the system. Only uninstall old application and install new application is allowed.